# I am getting an error when transforming datetime javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, iso8601, toisostring

I'm using `date.toISOString()` to use DateTime format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH: mm: ss'Z '", I must use ISO 8601 format. At the time of transformation, the time is showing it 5 hours in advance, that is, I am receiving for example this hour 2020-12-03 16:28:20 and at the time of transforming I show this 2020-12-03T21: 26: 52.000Z (5 hours in advance). I would like to know why it happens?

Thank you

Comment: Local timezone vs UTC

Comment: `2020-12-03 16:28:20` is your local PC time. `2020-12-03T21: 26: 52.000Z` is that same moment in time in UTC.

Comment: 2020-12-03 16:28:20  It is the time that I receive from my service provider, I need to show that same time but in ISO DateTime format

Comment: anyone have any solution?

Comment: Assuming the original timestamp is UTC, then `"2020-12-03 16:28:20".replace(' ','T') + 'Z'`